# How to pass dynamic number of columns?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, columnsorting

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[[100,'a_',1],
[150,'a_',6],
[200,'a_',6],
[120,'b_',2],
[220,'c_', 3],
[230,'d_', 4],
[500,'e_',5],[
110,'a_',6],
[130,'b_',6],
[140,'b_',12]], ['id','type','cnt'])
```

As is:

```
df.withColumn(
        "rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy(col("cnt").desc(), col("id").desc()))
    ).head(10)
```

To be. I want to make method

```
def rank(df, order):
    df.withColumn(
        "rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy(order))
    ).head(10)
```

I want to pass multiple columns for ordering (`col("cnt").desc(), col("id").desc()`).
If there's just one column, that's simple, but I should make a scalable method (to accept more columns). How to do it?

++)
If I want to another dynamic parameter, how to fix it?

```
def rank(df, ?, *order):
    df = df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(?).orderBy(*order))
    )
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `order` try using `*order`

I'm not sure what you want to do, but the following modified version of your `rank` function seems to work with different number columns provided.

```py
def rank(df, *order):
    df = df.withColumn(
        "rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy(*order))
    )
    return df
```

```py
rank(df, asc("id")).show()
# +---+----+---+----+
# | id|type|cnt|rank|
# +---+----+---+----+
# |100|  a_|  1|   1|
# |110|  a_|  6|   2|
# |150|  a_|  6|   3|
# |200|  a_|  6|   4|
# |120|  b_|  2|   1|
# |130|  b_|  6|   2|
# |140|  b_| 12|   3|
# |220|  c_|  3|   1|
# |230|  d_|  4|   1|
# |500|  e_|  5|   1|
# +---+----+---+----+

rank(df, col("cnt").desc(), col("id").desc()).show()
# +---+----+---+----+
# | id|type|cnt|rank|
# +---+----+---+----+
# |200|  a_|  6|   1|
# |150|  a_|  6|   2|
# |110|  a_|  6|   3|
# |100|  a_|  1|   4|
# |140|  b_| 12|   1|
# |130|  b_|  6|   2|
# |120|  b_|  2|   3|
# |220|  c_|  3|   1|
# |230|  d_|  4|   1|
# |500|  e_|  5|   1|
# +---+----+---+----+
```

Comment: Thank you!! That I want!
If I want to "type" part also given dynamic, how to fix it?
I guess * is available use only one in parameter.
I'm modify upper question.

Comment: Yes, in that case it's impossible. But I had the case which you have now. I just decided to pass the whole window to this function. In your case, it would be `rank(df, w)`. Both of your parameters will go into window anyway, so to me that would look more understandable.